# Renaming file names in Linux with listing

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I want to rename all files in a directory  file names are 1.ABC, 2.ABC , 3.ABC and so on I want to rename them as 1.abc , 2.abc , 3.abc .... and so on respectively.

I have tried

```
 ls -1 *.ABC| xargs -I{}  mv {}  ${{}/ABC/abc}
```

but this does not seem to work gives error as

```
bash: ${{}/ABC/abc}: bad substitution.
```

I tried rename command also but that does not seem to be running on my system:

```
rename 's/\.ABC$/.abc/' *.ABC
```

gives me no results. I want to stick with first method that I tried if that can be corrected.

Comment: Also see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and the Unix & Linux SE question [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/1986)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `rename` utility then you can just do:

```
rename 's/ABC/abc/' *.ABC
```

Or else you can use this simple `for` loop:

```
for file in *.ABC; do
   mv "$file" "${file/.*/.abc}"
done
```

Comment: It did , thanks anubhava , I was actually aware of this ,method . I was actually looking for  a correction in my first approach     `ls -1 *.ABC| xargs -I{}  mv {}  ${{}/ABC/abc}`  but I think it only can be used when you want to append files names while renaming and not when you want to replace or remove some part of string from the new file names  as in    `ls -1 *.ABC| xargs -I{} mv {} {}_bkp`

Comment: In general, you should avoid parsing output of `ls`